# Inner LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method as follow

```
private void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, Container container, string solutionPrefix)
{
   var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .Where(a.FullName.StartsWith(solutionPrefix))
                .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                .Where(x => !x.IsAbstract && !x.IsGenericTypeDefinition);
   //Rest of the code...
}
```

Now I want to refactor the code in a way that **solutionPrefix** parameter is an array of strings and in the first Where clause it selects all the assemblies that their name starts with any of the items in the solutionPrefix array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this overload of the [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-2.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) extension method.

```
.Where(x => solutionPrefix.Any(e => x.FullName.StartsWith(e)))
```